# The difference between residuals(XX) and XX$residuals of glm(y~x, family=poisson(link=log)) in R

Tags: r

I'm executing the following program `glm(y~x, family=poisson(link=log))`. I can't understand the difference between `residuals(XX)` and `XX$residuals`. I'd like to know where `residuals(XX)` and `XX$residuals` come from, and the relationship to `deviance`. Please give me some advice.

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
y<-c(2,3,7,6)
r<-glm(y~x,family=poisson(link="log"))
#Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x, family = poisson(link = "log"))
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            x  
#     0.4978       0.3691  
#Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  2 Residual
#Null Deviance:      3.961 
#Residual Deviance: 1.064        AIC: 18.13

deviance(r)# [1] 1.063829
sum(residuals(r)^2)# [1] 1.063829
residuals(r)# -0.2530074 -0.2434844  0.8533358 -0.4608144

sum(r$residuals^2)# [1] 0.234646
r$residuals# -0.1594713 -0.1283418  0.4061298 -0.1667391
```

Comment: hint: take a look at `stats::residuals.glm`

Comment: The help (on the relevant functions) is the best place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I got it.

## residuals(r)=residuals(x,type="deviance")

```
residuals(r)# -0.2530074 -0.2434844  0.8533358 -0.4608144
residuals(r,type="deviance")# -0.2530074 -0.2434844  0.8533358 -0.4608144
```

## METHOD

```
mu<-r$fitted# 2.379455 3.441716 4.978203 7.200626
poisson.dev<-function(y,mu) 2*(y*log(ifelse(y==0,1,y/mu))-(y-mu))
sqrt(poisson.dev(y,r$fitted))*ifelse(r$fitted<y,1,-1)# -0.2530074 -0.2434844      0.8533358
```

## RELATIONSHIP_deviance(r)=sum(residuals(r)^2)=sum(residuals(r,type="deviance")^2

```
deviance(r)# [1] 1.063829
sum(residuals(r)^2)# [1] 1.063829
```

## r$residuals=residuals(x,type="working")

```
r$residuals#-0.1594713 -0.1283418  0.4061298 -0.1667391
residuals(r,type="working")#-0.1594713 -0.1283418  0.4061298 -0.1667391
(y-r$fitted)/r$fitted#-0.1594713 -0.1283418  0.4061298 -0.1667391
```